# R statistical test for two groups with categorial data

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, statistical-significance

I have two groups, in which three possible outcomes appeared at different frequencies, and I wanna know, if there is a significant difference in-between the groups.

For instance, I have two potatoe fields, field A and field B. The potatoes grew either tall, normal, or small in the respected fields e.g.:

```
    Amount of potatoes
    Tall  -   Normal  -  Small
A:   30         10       2
B:   48         12       1
```

"71% percent of the potatoes on field A grew tall."
Is this significantly different to on field B?

Was looking for some Anova test but couldn't find a suitable. Also most were looking for numeric data with mean values etc.

Comment: A chi square test is probably what you are looking for.  This is a better question for the cross validate site.

Comment: Thanks Dave! Chi square looks good. But it is only usable for two variables, is that correct?

Comment: Your example only has two variables. The `loglin()` function provides a way to handle multidimensional tables. Also a possibility is Poisson regression using `glm()`.

Comment: $\chi^2$ is good for any number of variables. I also like the $G-test$, which is a likelihood ratio test of nested (multinomial) logistic regression models. I show that [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/551623/247274), and you can apply my code to nested multinomial logistic regression models, since you have a $3$-category $y$.